# Finding $\omega$ from $\omega^{-2}=1-\epsilon\eta_0-\epsilon^2\eta_1-\epsilon^3\eta_2+\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, power-series

I am reading a book on Nonlinear differential equations and the author states the following:

For sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, it holds
$$\omega^{-2}=1-\epsilon\eta_0-\epsilon^2\eta_1-\epsilon^3\eta_2+\ldots$$

Then

$$\omega=1+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2(\frac{1}{2}\eta_1+\frac{3}{8}\eta_0^2)+\epsilon^3(\frac{1}{2}\eta_2+\frac{3}{4}\eta_0\eta_1+\frac{15}{48}\eta_0^3)+\ldots $$

I tried several things, but I am not sure how to find it. It looks like kind of a geometric series, but I am stuck. Any hint or helo is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to obtain the first few terms is to binomial expand
$$
\omega=(\omega^{-2})^{-1/2}=(1-\underbrace{(\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2\eta_1+\dots)}_{\text{small if }\epsilon\text{ is small}})^{-1/2}
$$
and you get
\begin{align*}
\omega &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}k (-1)^k(\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2\eta_1+\dots)^k\\
&=1+\frac12(\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2\eta_1+\dots)\\
&\hphantom{=1}+\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac32}{2}(\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2\eta_1+\dots)^2\\
&\hphantom{=1}+\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac52}{3!}(\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2\eta_1+\dots)^3+\dots
\end{align*}
which you collect the terms in ascending order of $\epsilon$, note that only terms up to $(\epsilon\eta_0+\epsilon^2\eta_1+\dots)^k$ contributes to the $\epsilon^k$ term.

---

If you want the full series written explicitly, you can obtain it by using
$f(u):=(1-u)^{-1/2}$, $g(\epsilon):=1-\omega(\epsilon)^{-2}$ in the [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) and you get
$$
\omega(\epsilon)=f(g(\epsilon))=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\epsilon^k
\cdot\sum_{\sum_{j=1}^k jm_j=n}\binom{-\tfrac12}{\sum_{j=1}^k m_j}(-1)^k\prod_{j=1}^k\eta_{j-1}^{m_j}.
$$

Comment: I just realised, in the binomial expansion there is a $(-1)^k$ missing. For example $\binom{-1/2}{1}=-1/2$, which turns with $(-1)^1$ into $1/2$. Other than that: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Thanks, corrected.